# Is there a way to get MySQL to return the row produced by an INSERT command?

Tags: php, mysql

I've done basic MySQL for a while now, but nothing beyond that. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the row echoed back to me, or something, when I insert a new row into a table. Basically I have a table with an autonumbered field, and I want to be able to get that autonumber as quickly and painlessly as possible. If I can't have the row returned to me, is there something else I should do short of just running a second query for the highest autonum? Wouldn't that allow for the (slight, very very slight) chance that the table has been updated by some other process or user, and that is not the right number anymore? Currently I just do a search for a row with exactly the contents that I just input, and even that seems to be causing me problems.

I'm using PHP 5.1, and MySQL 5.0.45 it looks like.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are looking for LAST_INSERT_ID() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: N.B.: If you're talking about getting this within PHP, use PHP's mysql_insert_id function - **don't attempt to issue a "LAST_INSERT_ID()" SQL query from within PHP**.

Comment: @middaparka: People who care about points won't answer his question. People who appreciate a good question and who are interested in knowledge don't care about points.

Comment: @aaaa bbbb Sorry, but that's the way Stack Overflow is supposed to work as defined by the FAQ. (Otherwise there are lots of pointless open questions that have really been answered.) Incidentally, it's not as if I even have a vested interested - I've not answered this question, merely added an advisory comment or two.

Comment: @middaparka: Thanks for the info. I don't mean to be snippy, but I see that comment too often. I think bad questions should be down voted, and good questions should be up voted, regardless if the person asking the question is usually discourteous.

Comment: @middaparka - I accept every answer that I get that's correct. I've only got like, five questions in here, and a few of them haven't produced any real solution. One, I think put the answer I found myself (which might not count?). I guess thanks for the tip, though. I'm just looking over this one now, but it looks like I'll probably find something I can use here.

Comment: @Pekka - why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function : [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

It returns the ID generated in the last query

Comment: Does this answer his secondary question, "Wouldn't that allow for the (slight, very very slight) chance that the table has been updated by some other process or user, and that is not the right number anymore? "

Comment: @aaaa bbbb - As PHP's mysql_insert_id would be called on the same connection as the query, it'll always return the ID from that query. i.e.: It's not affected by activity from other users.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks @middaparka. I'm using PDO, so it looks like I should use PDO::lastInsertId. Anyone know if that will cause me any other problems?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which is works in the scope of current connection.

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: How do you respond to middaparka's comment that you should not attempt to issue a "LAST_INSERT_ID()" SQL query from within PHP? I think I'd go with the built-in PHP function mysql_insert_id.

Comment: I would agree LAST_INSERT_ID() isn't meant to be used anywhere but at the SQL level in your scripts. If you're attempting to get the value from PHP than I suggest to follow middaparka's advice.

Comment: Thanks Sergei! I'm going with the PHP version, but I appreciate knowing about this as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use mysql_insert_id is ok, but it you truly want to avoid race conditions, just do a select after the insert with the values that you've just inserted. If these values could not be unique, insert also a timestamp calculated previously. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php#95584:

```
<?php
$date = date('U');
$db->query("INSERT INTO TABLE table VALUES('', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '". $date ."'");
$res = $db->query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE a_col = 'a' AND b_col = 'b' AND c_col = 'c' AND d_col = 'd' AND temp_id = '".$date."'");
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt to link to the source where you copy code from, you know... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php#95584

Comment: This is completely unnecessary. PHP's mysql_insert_id is connection based and hence as long as the running PHP script doesn't issue another SQL query, the previous insert ID will remain intact.

Comment: @middaparke: and when you're not using auto increment fields or you insert multiple rows with one command?

Comment: If you're inserting multiple rows and needs the IDs of each one, then don't do a multiple insert. It's that simple.

Comment: Ok. No auto increment field then! ;)

Comment: @sergi: Wasn't my question about auto-increment though? I'm not sure I understand how this is helpful to me.

And is your solution different from my statement: "Currently I just do a search for a row with exactly the contents that I just input"?

Comment: @ben as you are only inserting one row at a time, and you have an auto-increment id, using mysql_insert_id is ok. Forget my suggestion.